# show that $F= \underset{n\geqslant1}{\bigcap} \left\{ x \in X, d(x,F) < \frac{1}{n} \right\}.$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $F$ be a closed set from a metric space $(X,d)$ , show that $$F= \underset{n\geqslant1}{\bigcap} \left\{ x \in X, d(x,F) < \frac{1}{n} \right\}.$$
My attempt :  $\Rightarrow)$
for all $x \in X$,  $ x\in F\iff d(x,F)=0$, then  $x \in \underset{n\geqslant1}{\bigcap} \left\{ x \in X, d(x,F) < \frac{1}{n} \right\} $

$\Leftarrow)$ for all $n\geqslant 1$, $0\leqslant d(x,F) < \frac{1}{n} \xrightarrow[n\to \infty]{}0,$ then $0\leqslant d(x,F) <0 $ !! ( can a strict inequality became broad ? this is my question ? )

Comment: When you reason with limits of sequences, strict inequalities *always* become broad.

Comment: It should be $0 \leq d(x,F) \leq 0$, which forces $d(x,F) = 0$. Also, you should state why $d(x,F) = 0$ if and only if $x \in F$ since this is not always true (what if $F$ was open).

Comment: @Mindlack thanks, but can someone prove it?

Comment: @philbo_baggins For $F$ closed, it's true.

Comment: @math_student: it works the other way: why would strict inequalities remain strict? (Hint: when you choose $x \in F$, your reasoning shows precisely it cannot happen). What we *can* prove is that if $a_n,b_n$ are convergent sequences to $\alpha$ and $\beta$ respectively, and $a_n \leq b_n$ then $\alpha \leq \beta$.

Comment: thanks all of you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Generally, limits always transform strict into large hence the result.

(Strict always implies large actually)

Think of $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ :

$$0<a_n$$ implies $$0\leq a_n$$ which is convenient with taking the limit